# Gui wallet log in issue

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon

I installed the Gui Wallet and created a wallet. However, if I want to access this wallet now I am always at the beginning of the Gui wallet setup steps. I always have to restore my already existing wallet with my mnemonic seed and cant just log in with my password. Resulting issue is, that if I restore my wallet from my mnemonic seed I automatically create another account (as I can see in my folders) However I cant start it from there. Does anybody have an idea where I messed up?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? It seems the config of the GUI is not properly saved.

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: During the setup, can you choose a different directory for the wallet file than the default one?